# cordova firebase google login - Login Error!! error: The redirect operation has been cancelled by the user before finalizing

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

The sign in page opens and I log in with my Gmail id then it directs back to the app then shows this error. Not sure where I am missing.

I have added only two js file for firebase.

firebase-app.js
firebase-auth.js

```
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var configfirebase = {
    apiKey: "***********************",
    authDomain: "*****************.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://f*************.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "************",
    storageBucket: "************",
    messagingSenderId: "**********",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(configfirebase);
</script>


    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
function firebaselogin() {

    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function() {
      return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult(); // never reach here.
    }).then(function(result) {
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;  // never reach here.
      var user = result.user;
      app.dialog.alert('Login success!! Welcome:' + result.user );
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
     app.dialog.alert('Login error!! error:' + errorMessage );
      // reach here and shows error.
    });


}
```

I have read several post regarding same topic but none of them giving answer by using the default auth domain. Somebody has resolve by using custom domain but please help me with this.

[image]

List of cordova plugin I have

`cordova plugin list
branch-cordova-sdk 2.6.24 "branch-cordova-sdk"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-browsertab 0.2.0 "cordova-plugin-browsertab"
cordova-plugin-buildinfo 2.0.2 "BuildInfo"
cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support 1.6.0 "Cordova CocoaPods Dependency Support"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 4.3.0 "Custom URL scheme"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 3.0.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.2 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-firebase-auth-google 1.1.6 "Firebase Authentication"
cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication 1.0.1 "cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-spotify 0.5.0 "cordova-spotify"
cordova-spotify-oauth 0.1.10 "cordova-spotify-oauth"
cordova-support-android-plugin 1.0.1 "cordova-support-android-plugin"
cordova-support-google-services 1.2.1 "cordova-support-google-services"
cordova-universal-links-plugin 1.2.1 "Universal Links Plugin"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the docs again from top to bottom. I found that I had missed to add a plugin and below `singleTask` line to `config.xml`.

[screenshot for docs](http://prntscr.com/kzg2bx)

Use `singleTask` if using for android application.

## Substitute *com.firebase.cordova* with the iOS bundle ID of your app.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable URL_SCHEME=com.firebase.cordova --save

<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
```

Where `com.firebase.cordova` is your application widget id which is given in `config.xml`.

---

### Note: Just a small message I would like to give. Please follow docs from top to bottom strictly to avoid such error.

I ignore that installation because I couldn't understand how do I copy multi line code into command prompt and thought it will give error. So I skipped it and run into this problem.

Now I added it and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

**ALSO**

I am using PhoneGap Build. The problem is Universal-links tag is not copied to AndroidManifest.xml. So the solution is

1. Install cordova-universal-links-plugin-fix
2. If you want to keep universal-links tag in config.xml keep it. But also add this to **config.xml**

**In widget tag on top add**

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

The add following code **anywhere in config.xml** I prefer before plugins or beside unvirsal-links tag

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application/activity">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="****-***.firebaseapp.com" android:pathPrefix="/__/auth/callback" android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</config-file>
```

Now when app is build either with phonegapbuild or local cordova CLI, it copies the universal-links data which was supposed to be in manifest file. When app runs and firebase.auth().getRedirectResult() is called it will not give any error which was something like

*auth/cancelled by user. The redirect was cancelled by user before finalizing*

User building app using cordova CLI please after running cordova build android make sure you have the above intent-filter tag under activity tag in the manifest file.